# Is there a webhook for settlements?

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-webhooks

Does authorize.net provide any web hooks for settlements? The [documentation doesn't have it listed](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/webhooks.html#Event_Types_and_Payloads).

We'd like to update our database once an order has settled (for the purpose of providing void or refund options).  If you have done this before and didn't use webhooks, how did you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no webhook for settlements. However, since they occur daily, and at the same time each day, you can have a regularly scheduled script (e.g. cron job) use the [Transaction Details API](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/transaction_reporting.html) to get settlement information.

Comment: In the sandbox they don't occur at the same time (between 9 PM and 12:15AM my local time is what I'm seeing) - I'll look into when production occurs.